# pull down UItableView to switch view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have to design a view controller that has top view controller and bottom view controller. And the root view of  top view controller is UITableView. As we know, super view of UITableView is UIScrollView, so i want to modify the UITableView that when pull over 60px, it will show the bottom view controller. I have read the UITableView and UIScrollView class reference again and again, but can not  find any solution for this. Does anyone know it? Thanks.

[image]

====================================================================================================================================================================

### I have solve with it. please check https://github.com/yishuiliunian/DZPullDownViewController.git

Comment: What that mean:"I design a view controller that has top view controller and bottom view controller" ?

Comment: like slide menu, i have two view controllers. One is on the top, other is on the bottom. initing

Comment: when initing, it only shows the top one, and when i pull down the top one , it will show the bottom one.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods in your view controller (which contains `UITableView`):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if(self.tableView.contentOffset.y<-70)
    {
       // Write your code here (To load new view controller)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have try it already.but the when i set the frame of self.tableview. the tableview.contentoff change to (0,0)


<pre><code>`- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if(self.tableView.contentOffset.y<-70)
    {
       self.view.frame = CGRectSetY(self.view.frame, -self.tableView.contentOffSet.y);
    }
}`</code></pre>

Comment: i have solve it .github:https://github.com/yishuiliunian/DZPullDownViewController.git

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement `UIScrollView`'s delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll` in your controller.
2. Observe scroll view's `contentOffset` property. If `scrollView.contentOffset.y` is smaller than `-60.f`, then show your bottom view.
   Hope this helps! Good Luck!

Comment: I have try it already.but the when i set the frame of self.tableview. the tableview.contentoffset change to (0,0), it's strange